# Using BGL to color lit an Object from the Viewport objects

Tags: selection-tools, bgl

I am figuring out a way to Color lit a object using BGL, but I have never encountered with BGL, so I would like to figure out how you could lit this object let's say obj from this code

```
import bpy

for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    if obj.name.startswith('LIT_'):
        obj = # Needs to be color lit
```

Although we can just have append a material with viewport color set to some color and apply it to the target object, but I want to Color-highlight or whatever it is in image, using BGL. Thank you!
[image]